# Fan Noise Reduction AsRock motherboard + AMD Ryzen

Tags: sound, fan, noise

I am asking this question because I noticed there wasn't an obvious answer for beginners.

The problem is very simple: I have a pretty noisy Wraith Spire CPU fan. Normally, it could run at a silent mode (set in the bios setup), it doesn't seem to slow down. This a serious issue for me since I have a set of open-back headphones that I don't want to give up, but might have to, because I can't seem to get to solve the issue.

Is there any way I could reduce the fan speed through some software? At least for when I am just listening to music and not running any other software.

Comment: First thing to check is your CPU temps, high temps should equal high fan speeds, and don't want to reduce.  If CPU around 40 to 60 and you have high fan, something needs adjustment or is wonky.

Comment: To control fan/s from OS, need to know if they have sensors that OS can read.  Would install ```sensors``` first and maybe ```psensors``` if you want a GUI.

Comment: I did install psensor and my cpu barely reaches 30°, but the fan constantly works at 1600 RPM, even though I am barely running anything on it.

Comment: See if there is a bios update for your system.  It is low fan speed, but don't expect that till temp warms up.  Look for 'fan control ubuntu' in google or here.  Fan itself nice and solid?

Comment: Run `sensors-detect`, does it detect anything in the SuperIO section?

Comment: Try running sensors-detect and fancontrol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Asrock motherboard you have but chances are the fan speed is adjustable in the bios, in the hardware section. Asrock boards usually have a high level of adjustment options built in most have the option to graph 5 different speeds to 5 different temperature settings. For example in [this manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/A320M-HDV.pdf) page 56 to gives you an idea.